# How to call Twitter's Update_With_Media and have embedded images link to external site?

Tags: twitter, instagram

When someone shares a photo from Instagram, the tweet displayed contains an imagine inline preview, but the link contained within the Tweet points to the Instagram site.

Based on my reading of the Twitter developer api, I think they are somehow able to modify the expanded_url and display_url of the generated media entity to have its link point to the Instagram location.

However, I don't know how to specify this as part of the update_with_media call, how do I go about using the Twitter api to have my embedded image links point to an external site?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

The feature Instagram used is called [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards). Twitter Cards enables you to add additional meta data to your websites that will be picked up by Twitter whenever a link to that page is shared in a Tweet.

So for example, to attach a photo to a tweet that contains a url with a photo in it that you want to attach (i.e. http://www.bahndr.com/Draft/Caption/1255741393/60269593) , you would need to add the following  tags to the linked url page:

```
<meta property="twitter:card" content="photo"/>
<meta property="twitter:url" content="http://www.bahndr.com/Draft/Caption/1255741393/60269593"/>
<meta property="twitter:title" content="#Windows"/>
<meta property="twitter:description" content="I guess I won't be checking in today!"/>
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://www.bahndr.com/service/rest/Objects/203216285-imageurl.jpg"/>
<meta property="twitter:site" content="@bahndr"/>
```

You need to be approved by Twitter for Cards on your site to start appearing.

And voila, Robert is your mother's brother, you have an attached photo to your tweet much like Instagram used to have.